# Prop: Suppose $\alpha$ is lower bound of $E$ and $\beta$ is an upper bound of $E$. Then, $\alpha \leq \beta$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Prop:** Let $E$ be a non-empty subset of an ordered set. Suppose $\alpha$ is lower bound of $E$ and $\beta$ is an upper bound of $E$. Then, $\alpha \leq \beta$.

**Pf:** Let $x \in E$ then $\alpha  \leq x$ and $x \leq \beta $. Since $E$ is a subset of an ordered set, we have transitivity such that $\alpha  \leq x, \space x \leq \beta \implies \alpha \leq x \leq \beta \implies \alpha \leq \beta $

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I'm happy to hear it.